# problem about inner semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be a group which is the product $G=NH$ of subgroup $N,H\subset G$ where $N$ is normal.

Let $N\cap H=\{1\}$.

I am trying to show that that there is an iso $G\cong N\rtimes H$, with the automorphism by conjugation on itself.

What isomorphism could I use? I tried various different ones but most weren't even homomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

Let the elements of $N \rtimes H$ be expressed as ordered pairs $(n,h)$, subject to the usual multiplication rule $(n,h)(n',h') = (nhn'h^{-1},hh')$.

Define a map $f : N \rtimes H \to G$ by the formula $f(n,h)=nh$.

Check that $f$ is a homomorphism (should be easy).

$f$ is onto since $G=NH$.

$f$ is one-to-one since $N \cap H = \{1\}$.

So $f$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

The homomorphism

$$\phi:H\to\text{Aut}\,N\;,\;\;\phi(h)(n):=n^h:=hnh^{-1}\;\;\;\text{does the trick}$$

Comment: yes, we are given that. now i would like to show that $G\cong N\rtimes H$. sorry maybe my wording was confusing.

Comment: But that follows at once from $\;G=NH\cong N\rtimes H\;$